# Libre Office Base in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice, database

Libre Office Base does not come installed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  It is not in the Ubuntu Software repository.  The questions on this are all over a year or two old.

I need a database for Ubuntu.  I'm concerned that Libre Office Base might not work with 16.04 or it would be in the repository.

What can the experts recommend for a full featured (and free) database for Ubuntu 16.04?  I know you do not recommend Open Office which was my pre-Ubuntu database.

Thank you for giving me the correct name to pull it up in the repository.  I had search for Libre Office Base, and nothing came up.

It is now installed.

Comment: Why do you think ...base is not in the repositories?  The name is libreoffice-base

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to install using:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

or, if you want the full installation of LibreOffice, use:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

More details can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice).